# Can grpc service be hosted in .Net Framework or .Net Standard

Tags: .net, grpc

I grabbed grpc server example online, and was able to start the server (in .net core) and create a client that could hit the endpoint. However, I was trying to change my server to point to .net framework (or .net standard) instead, but I cannot figure out how to get the server code to compile. I get an error when trying to use the same method `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` because I believe it is a .net core functionality only:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {

                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    // This endpoint will use HTTP/2 and HTTPS on port 5001.
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    });
                });

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, are there any examples of how to start the server using .net standard/framework?

Comment: You are using the grpc-dotnet implementation and thus your initialization code is ASP.NET Core specific (and you won't be able to run it on desktop .NET framework or compile under netstandard). There is another implementation of gRPC C# that will allow you to use it on .NET framework. See the notes on two C# implementations here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/csharp#grpc-c